# Is there a way to know when a set of app engine task queue tasks have completed?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

is there a way to determine when a set of Google App Engine tasks (and child tasks they spawn) have *all* completed?

Let's say that I have 100 tasks to execute and 10 of those spawn 10 child tasks each. That's 200 tasks. Let's also say that those child tasks might spawn more tasks, recursively, etc...

Is there a way to determine when all tasks have completed? I tried using the app engine pipeline API, but it doesn't look like it's going to work out for my particular use case, even though it is a great API.

My use case is that I want to make a whole bunch of rate limited URL fetch calls while concurrently writing to a blob. At the end of all the URL fetch calls, I want to finalize the blob.

I found the solution with the pipeline API, but it does so much writing to the datastore that it wouldn't be cost effective for me with how often I need to run the pipeline.

Comment: Did you already took a look at Fantasm? there is an interesting part of the article describe fanning in: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/fantasm.html#in, and can you predict the amount of task spawned in advance?

Comment: Hi Proppy, thanks for that. My example is one of fan-out, and the fantasm article you mention talks about using fan-in to optimize the counting operation. That might come in handy, but I do not know the number of tasks beforehand for my particular use case, so I'm thinking it's going to mean I have to do some recursive counting of some sort. I am hoping someone has something that can get me away from that.

Comment: How have you determined that the pipeline API won't be cost effective? Datastore writes are individually pretty cheap, particularly where indexing isn't required.

Comment: @Nick: For me, if I issue 90 jobs, and all each job does is a URL fetch, it costs 10 cents and takes 6+ minutes to run with the default queue at 5/s rate. For these 90 URL fetches, there are 5K-6K entities being written to the datastore to do whatever accounting. I might play around with it a bit more, but I've been working with it for the last few days and it does not look promising. I don't want to pay $0.10 for 90 URL fetches.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way around writing to a persistent storage medium of some sort, and the datastore is the only game in town. You could write your own server to track completions using a backend, but that's an awful lot of overhead for a simple task. Using the pipeline API is your best bet.

Comment: I'm fine with writing to the datastore. I'm not OK using the pipeline API to do it if it means that API is going to write 5K large entities to the datastore for 90-120 jobs. I'm not sure my code is optimized. I'm not even sure if I'm using the pipeline API correctly. I've had help from the project maintainer on the code, and while I can't say it performs like this for all use cases, this is what I'm experiencing on mine. $0.10 for 90-120 URL fetches and all the datastore accounting that goes along with that (5K+ large entities being written)

Comment: @JohnWheeler I'm really surprised at that. What's the nature of the entities? I can't think of any reason it would require anything like that many entities, or why they'd be 'large'.

Comment: this is the result of me running my pipeline 4 times. Each pipeline invocation ends up doing around 90-120 jobs. http://i.imgur.com/jigBP.png -- Let me know if you're interested in seeing anything specific.

Comment: none of the 21K entities above are from my application BTW. My application is only running a pipeline at this point and doesn't do anything else.