# App Engine Java - Execute final event when all tasks have completed their process

Tags: java, google-app-engine, queue, task, pipeline

I'm developing an App Engine application where an http request spawn a undefined number of tasks (can be 10, can be 100, can be 1000).
Those tasks will run on PUSH queue.

When all the task has finished, I need a conclusive action which will get the status of each task and creates a final report (a summary of all executed operations). For this example let's say it is an email delivery.

An additional info is that the task are grouped by a common value (let's call group_id). When all the tasks of the same group_id have finished, the event can be executed for this particular group. This specification I made is because if other tasks are still running but there are of other group_id, the event for this group can be executed as well.

I'm wondering which is the best approach to implement something like this.
Of course there can be a lot of "homemade" solution where (for example) I save the status of each task inside a Datastore entity and retrieve each status or else each task can "question" its brothers and check if it is the last one.

My question is if there is a more high-level solution to implement this behaviour.

With a quick search I found the pipeline API [1] which seems to be promising, but I'm not sure to understand if it the correct solution for the behaviour I need.
On stackoverflow this library is very well acclamed, so maybe is the right way to do it.

Here some of the thread I read

- [How can I tell if a set of app engine tasks have all completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964234/how-can-i-tell-if-a-set-of-app-engine-tasks-have-all-completed)
- [Writing to an appengine blob asynchronously and finalizing it when all tasks complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996760/writing-to-an-appengine-blob-asynchronously-and-finalizing-it-when-all-tasks-com)
- [Is there a way to know when a set of app engine task queue tasks have completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027757/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-a-set-of-app-engine-task-queue-tasks-have-completed)

If I understand correctly the implementation for this Pipeline API, when a Job starts it provides a jobId to test if it has finished or is still running.
If so, this requires an external poll on the job status, which is not my case. My particular need is when the last finished, the final event is automatically triggered

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines

Comment: One could argue that the pipelines are a "homemade" solution as well. It basically uses the same principle where you store the status in the datastore. Homemade is fine with me, so i'd go with that. If you want parallel execution and you don't have to use app engine you might want to look into Google's Dataflow which is basically made for exactly this purpose. That is assuming you're processing data here. Other than that i have implemented state machines on app engine which work similar to pipelines and use the datastore to store contexts. A cron job can check whether all contexts are finished

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single Datastore entity to store group_id, the number of tasks started and the number of tasks completed. Upon completion each task updates this entity, and if the number of tasks completed equals the number of tasks started, creates the "final" task to generate a report.